# using git remote command outside the repository dir

Tags: git, location, git-remote

Is there any way to pass a location of the repository to the command `git remote` so the command will take it as a subject to work on?

I want to call

```
git remote add origin <url>
```

outside the repository directory, is it possible to pass the repository location as a parameter to the command?

[git remote documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) - do you see any ways to do that?

Comment: [`git -C`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git--Cltpathgt), [`git 
--git-dir`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git---git-dirltpathgt).

Comment: `git -C <path-to-repository> remote add origin <url>` worked well. Thank you, please put that code in the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git--Cltpathgt

```
git -C <path>
```

Run as if git was started in  instead of the current working directory.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git---git-dirltpathgt

```
git --git-dir=<path>
```

Set the path to the repository. This can also be controlled by setting the `GIT_DIR` environment variable. It can be an absolute path or relative path to current working directory.